# How to save a list of analytic expressions in a file?

Tags: export, save

I use *Mathematica* to calculate many analytic expressions, some of them are generated by a loop process, the result can be a vector with a index, e.g., `f[i]`.

Now I want to save them in a file, for example *Mathematica* package file `"result.m"`, and other expression may also want to be added into this file. The file should looks like this:

```
f[1] = ;
f[2] = ;
...
f[10] = ;

fsum = ;
gxyz = ;
```

This should be a simple task, but I can't figure out the solution. Does anyone know how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html):

```
Save["test.m", {f, fsum, gxyz}]
```

For instance:

```
Table[f[i] = i^2, {i, 10}];
fsum = 385;
gxyz = "blabla";

Save["test.m", {f, fsum, gxyz}];

FilePrint["test.m"]
```

> f[1] = 1
>
> f[2] = 4
>
> f[3] = 9
>
> f[4] = 16
>
> f[5] = 25
>
> f[6] = 36
>
> f[7] = 49
>
> f[8] = 64
>
> f[9] = 81
>
> f[10] = 100
>
> fsum = 385
>
> gxyz = "blabla"

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's simple and works well!